# Angular.js: How can I return a content without view? Returning atom feed to users

Tags: angularjs, xml-parsing, mime-types, atom-feed, defaultview

I plan to generate an Atom feed inside my AngularJS controller. A want to generate a view, but not on the server-side, because I want to replace the URI with a new AngularJS route.

Now I know how to write XML with JavaScript, but I have no idea about how to returning a XML content without a view.

My route setting is quite normal like below. It uses `templateUrl` to render a partial view.

```
.when('/posts', {
            templateUrl: 'theme/post_list.html',
            controller: PostsController
        })
```

Is it possible to serve XML content without a view using AngularJS? Like so:

```
.when('/posts.atom', {
            controller: PostsController
        })
```

Generating the angular.js routed Atom feed on the server-side is possible, but I don't want it.

Comment: seems like you need to write some `service`

Comment: @Cherniv Okay, I can write a service or a factory to create atom feed. And then? What I can do is calling a service via controller and get feed xml. How can I return atom xml to feed client or a browser?

Comment: It's enough to have one main controller to work with services , no? what is atom xml?

Comment: @Cherniv This is my dumb question. This is not possible with client-side programming. I solved this issue with server-side generation.

Comment: you welcome , glad you solved it

Answer (score 0):

Use the following process:

- Append an `<object>` or `<iframe>` to the DOM with the XML within the tag

OR:

- Return Atom from the service
- Store in a documentFragment
- Use [transformToFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_the_Mozilla_JavaScript_interface_to_XSL_Transformations) or [DOMParser](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/10/15/domparser-and-xmlserializer-in-ie9-beta.aspx) to create a view
- Use [XMLSerializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/XMLSerializer) to convert the view to a string
- Insert an [XML stylesheet](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-stylesheet/) into the string:

  ```
    <?xml-stylesheet href="feed.css"?>
  ```
- Use the string as the value of the `srcdoc` attribute:

  ```
    <iframe srcdoc="{{atomfeed}}" height="95%" width="100%">
  ```

For example:

```
$scope.atomstyle='<?xml-stylesheet href="feed.css"?>'
$scope.atomboilerplate='<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">'
$scope.atomhead='<title></title><link></link>'
$scope.atomcontent='<entry><title></title><link></link></entry>';
$scope.atomtail='</feed>'

$scope.atomfeed=String().concat
 (
 $scope.atomstyle, 
 $scope.atomboilerplate,
 $scope.atomhead,
 $scope.atomcontent,
 $scope.atomtail
 )
```

**References**

- [insert an iframe into page dynamically in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20165780/1113772)
- [XML 1.0, Section 2.8: Prolog and Document Type Declaration](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-prolog-dtd)
- [Embedded Content - HTML5: srcdoc](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#attr-iframe-srcdoc)
- [How to show RSS in an iframe or div?](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/923274)
- [Mozilla source: feeds/subscribe.css](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/themes/windows/feeds/subscribe.css)
- [AngularJs (all versions) breaks on IE11 in document mode ie=8](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4137)
- [view-source: URI scheme](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-yevstifeyev-view-source-uri-00)
- [Feed View overrides XSLT stylesheet defined in XML document](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=338621)