# insert an iframe into page dynamically in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, iframe, angularjs-directive, ng-bind-html

I am trying to dynamically insert an iframe into a page with Angular 1.2. Here is the code:

html:

```
<div id="player_wrapper" ng-cloak>
    <div ng-bind-html="player"></div>
</div>
```

js:

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: url}).
    success(function(data, status) {
        $scope.player = data.html;
    }.......
```

So the data.html is a string that has a valid HTML starting with

```
<iframe ...>
```

The string contains also some div. So it could look like:

```
<iframe src='...' ...></iframe><div>some stuf</div>
```

I use in app.js 'ngSanitize'. What it shows is the div (after the iframe) but not the iframe  itself.

If I use jQuery, basically a

```
$(#'player_wrapper').html(data.html)
```

works fine... but trying to make it proper angularJS.

Any idea on why only the divs after the iframe are being displayed?

Many thanks all

Comment: Can you try using `ng-include`.

Comment: tried this:<div ng-include="player"></div> and get an error XMLHttpRequest (I'm developing locally so I have a file:// in url...)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`ngBindHtml` will pass your HTML through [`$sce.getTrustedHtml`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24sce#methods_gettrustedhtml) before displaying it. I suspect this is what would be removing your iframe.

[According to the docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angBindHtml) you can use [$sce.trustAsHtml](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24sce#methods_trustashtml) to avoid this check so long as you fully trust any HTML coming from this source - an iframe from an untrusted source could likely do a number on nasty things to visitors to your page.

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: url}).
    success(function(data, status) {
        $scope.player = $sce.trustAsHtml(data.html);
    }.......
```

Be careful! :)

Answer (score 8):

You need to use the `$sce` service as desribed in the [documentation of ng-bind-html](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.1/docs/api/ng.directive%3angBindHtml):

```
$scope.player = $sce.trustAsHtml('your html goes here');
```

See [this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/MIj215Ek4IGQog8uP5yq?p=preview) for an example:

Answer (score 4):

After much trouble I managed to get a nice setup going where I can dynamically load iframes into my page and pass information through to it.

I made this [a github project](https://github.com/james2doyle/angular-through-iframe/). It uses a single directive for passing raw input element information, and also uses `ngSanatize` for the `$sce.trustAsResourceUrl` function.

[Here is the live demo](http://james2doyle.github.io/angular-through-iframe/)